# I am getting the wrong percentage in pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, codeigniter

Below I have mentioned my code ↓

```php
public function get_cmp_vs_leads($date1,$date2)
        {
            //$date_from=$date1.' 00:00:00';
            //$date_end=$date2.' 23:59:59'; 
            $rows = $this->db->select("count(pm1ticket.id) as cnt,status_id");
                    $this->db->from("pm1ticket");
                    $this->db->join('pm1channelpartner_list','pm1channelpartner_list.partner_id = pm1ticket.channel_partner');
                    $this->db->where("pm1ticket.cr_date >=",$date1);
                    $this->db->where("pm1ticket.cr_date <=",$date2);
                    $this->db->where("pm1ticket.flag",1);
                    $this->db->where_in("pm1channelpartner_list.partner_id",explode(',',PARTNER_IDS));
                    $this->db->group_by('pm1ticket.status_id');
            $rows = $this->db->get();   
            //echo $this->db->last_query(); die; 
            return $rows->result_array();
        }
      
      public function get_non_booked_tkt_total($rep_id,$date1,$date2)
        {
            $rows = $this->db->select("count(pm1ticket.id) as cnt,status_id");
                $this->db->from("pm1ticket");
                $this->db->join('pm1channelpartner_list','pm1channelpartner_list.partner_id = pm1ticket.channel_partner');
                $this->db->where("pm1ticket.cr_date >=",$date1);
                $this->db->where("pm1ticket.cr_date <=",$date2);
                $this->db->where("pm1ticket.flag",1);
                $this->db->where_in("pm1channelpartner_list.partner_id",explode(',',PARTNER_IDS));
                $this->db->where('pm1ticket.status_id !=',CLOSED_STATUS);
                $this->db->group_by('pm1ticket.status_id');
        $rows = $this->db->get();   
        //echo $this->db->last_query(); die; 
        return $rows->result_array();
        }
      
      $cmp_vs_sts_wise_tkt = $this->dashboard_model->get_cmp_vs_leads($start_date,$end_date);   
            
        $finalcnt1 = array();
        foreach($cmp_vs_sts_wise_tkt as $kk =>$vv){
        if($vv['status_id'] != '0'){
        $finalcnt1[] = $vv['cnt'];
        }
        }   
    
        $sum1 = array_sum($finalcnt1);
    
        foreach($cmp_vs_sts_wise_tkt as $key =>$val)
        {
            if($val['status_id'] != '0')
            {
            $cmp_name =  $dtd[$val['status_id']]; 
            $perch = round(($val['cnt']/$sum1)*100);
            $tkt_stat1[]=array(name=>$cmp_name.'('.$perch.'%)',y=>intval($val['cnt']));
            $nonbooked_tkt[] = $val['cnt'];
            }
        }   
            
        $non_booked_wise_tkt = $this->dashboard_model->get_non_booked_tkt_total($rep_id_arr,$start_date,$end_date);
            
        $finalcntsnb = array();
            
        foreach($non_booked_wise_tkt as $kknb =>$vvnb){
            if($vvnb['status_id'] != '0' && $vvnb['status_id'] != ''){
            $finalcntsnb[] = $vvnb['cnt'];
            }
        }   
        $sumnb = array_sum($finalcntsnb);
        
        foreach($non_booked_wise_tkt as $kysnb =>$valsnb)
        {
            if($valsnb['status_id'] != '0' && $valsnb['status_id'] != ''){
                $percg = round(($valsnb['cnt']/$sum1)*100);             
                $non_booked[]=array(name=>$dtd[$valsnb['status_id']].'('.$percg.'%)',y=>intval($valsnb['cnt']));
                $non_booked_tkt[] = $valsnb['cnt'];
                $non_booked_bars[]=array(name=>$dtd[$valsnb['status_id']],y=>intval($valsnb['cnt']));           
            }
        }
        $data['booked_tkt_cnt'] = json_encode(array(array('name'=>'Remaining '.LEAD.'s'.'('.$percg.'%)','y'=>array_sum($non_booked_tkt)),array('name'=>CLOSED_STATUS_NM.' '.LEAD.'s'.'('.$perct.'%)','y'=>array_sum($booked_tkt))));
```

Here I have written some code to display the count and percentage for pie chart. I have used `get_cmp_vs_leads` function in modal to display the count with percentage according to the overall status and `get_non_booked_tkt_total` function is used to display the count with percentage of overall status excluding booked status but I am getting the percentage count is wrong. In the pie chart I have made two partition one is for booked leads and the other is for remaining leads, the percentage is coming properly for booked leads but for remaining leads it is coming wrong. can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is your error:

```
$percg = round(($valsnb['cnt']/$sum1)*100);
```

May be `$sum1` must be `$sumnb`